# proving a statement about Horner's method

Tags: polynomials, roots

I was reading about Horner's method and then I saw the following statement:

> If $f(x)$ is a polynomial such that: $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}x^{i}$,and if we want to >compute the 
>   value of this polynomial for $x=x_0$ then defining a sequence of constants :
>   $$b_n=a_n$$
>   $$b_{n-1}=a_{n-1}+b_{n}x_0$$
>   implies $$p(x_0)=b_0$$

well I understand this but the problem is here:

> Also it can be proven that; $$p\left(x\right)=\left(b_{1}+b_{2}x+...+b_{n}x^{n-
> 1}\right)\left(x-x_{0}\right)+b_{0}$$
>   I tried to figure it out, but still I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: @hardmath,the source is https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method,also it would be really appreciated if you help me with this problem :)

Comment: @hardmath,yes actually,and using different $x_0$'s generates different $b_i$'s, also if for $x_0$ ,$b_0=0$, implies this $x_0$ is indeed a root of the given polynomial,since $b_0=p(x)$.

Comment: Okay, one way to see this is by comparing the results of [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division), which produces exactly the division of $p(x)$ by $x-x_0$ with remainder $b_0= p(x_0)$ (the evaluation of the polynomial at $x_0$).  It will take me a bit to properly craft the $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Please take a look at this earlier Question, 
[Why does dividing a polynomial by x−a give the same quotient as evaluating it at x=a using synthetic division?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2928272/why-does-dividing-a-polynomial-by-x-a-give-the-same-quotient-as-evaluating-it)  If the Answer accepted there is not enough, I will add a new one. .

Comment: @hardmath,I looked at the page,but can you please add a new one?

Answer (score 0):

This is just algebra. Expand the RHS and collect the like powers of $x$:
$$
\begin{align}
&b_0 + (b_1+b_2x+\cdots+b_nx^{n-1})(x-x_0)\\
&=b_0 + b_1x + b_2x^2 +\cdots+b_nx^n-(b_1x_0+b_2x_0x+\cdots+b_nx_0x^{n-1})\\
&=\underbrace{(b_0-b_1x_0)}_{a_0}+
\underbrace{(b_1-b_2x_0)}_{a_1}x+
\underbrace{(b_2-b_3x_0)}_{a_2}x^2+\cdots+
\underbrace{(b_{n-1}-b_nx_0)}_{a_{n-1}}x^{n-1}+\underbrace{b_n}_{a_n}x^n\\
\end{align}
$$
In the final step we simply plug in the recursive definitions for $b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_n$, obtaining $p(x)$.